# Facebook Share button wrong link

Tags: php, facebook, url, button, share

I have a little issue with the Facebook Share button. It gets the actual url but some caracters aren't like it is normaly

*** My code ***

```
echo "<div class=\"fb-share-button\" data-href=\"http://exemple.com?image:$id:$extension\" data-layout=\"button\"></div>";
```

the result from the share button is :

```
http%3A%2F%2Fexemple.com%2F%3Fimage%15%253A.jpg
```

The caracters below seems to be taken wrong.

```
: / ?
```

Any help or explanation is very welcome.

Comment: try this:- echo '<div class="fb-share-button"   data-href="http://exemple.com?image:$id:$extension"  data-layout="button"></div>';

Comment: @anantkumarsingh I don't know why but i have the same result with single quotes

Comment: You need to show your button either on fiddle or on your site. because it's works for me.

Comment: _“The caracters below seems to be taken wrong. `: / ?`”_ – sounds like you have (only) just discovered what [URL percent encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) is. (In what way it presents a _problem_ is unclear however.)

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for the explanation i understand what is going on now

Answer (score 1):

The main reason why your code is not working,is that you are using a lot of `"`.
the solution is,to create 3 variables,like this:

```
$link="http://exemple.com?image:$id:$extension"
$button = "button"
$class = "fb-share-button"
```

and then,place them in your code:

```
echo "<div class=$class data-href=$link data-layout=$button></div>";
```